# MVC:If ID is equal to zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

what I've got is a edit page and a create page. That are two links in another page, I am trying to create a redirect when the user tries to press on the edit button, if there is no value in the id, the site will take the user to the add page.

```
Public ActionResult Edit (int id)
{
   if (Product.Id.Equals(null))
   {
      RedirectToAction("Add");
   }
//Edit Page Code is here
}
```

what I've got is wrong

Comment: You're "guessing what you've got is wrong." Have you not tried to run this? You should probably be checking for zero instead of `null`

Comment: I doubt if that is a good way to check for `null`: `Product.Id.Equals(null)`, because either it is not null or you get an exception. You just have to use `==`: `if (Product.Id == null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the id as nullable, either "int? id" or `"Nullable<int> id"`.

```
    Public ActionResult Edit (int? id)
    {
           if (!id.HasValue)
           {
             RedirectToAction("Add");
           }
           // Edit code goes here   

    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable to nullable.
Just put ? on your variable.

```
Public ActionResult Edit (int? id)
{
   if (Product.Id.Equals(id))
   {
     RedirectToAction("Add");
   }
}
```